# VirtualBox: Linux guest on OS X host won't update

Tags: linux, macos, virtualbox, virtual-machine, debian

I'm running a Debian Mint guest on an OS X host with VirtualBox.

1) So I run Update Manager in the Linux guest: 364 recommended updates are available.

2) Everything seems to be going fine.

3) After updating, Update Manager says the same 364 packages are available.

[image: updates available!]

This has happened 3 or 4 times with guest reeboots in between. I would of course like to update the Linux distro and see the words: "0 updates available." Any suggestions?

Some numbers:

OS X version is 10.7.2

VirtualBox is 4.1.6 r74713

Debian Mint is 32-bit version, Linux kernel is 2.6.39-2-468, Xfce is version 4.8.0.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open a Terminal and do:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

This will update your packages and upgrade to the latest distrobution. If there are no new distributions then you can do

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

to just upgrade your current applications to the latest versions.

You can always do

```
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

which will remove older dpkgs where a newer version has taken its place. However, this is not directly related to your issue.

Comment: Can't believe I didn't think of that!